# How to install and configure play-mailer, for playframework 2.5.x

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to install the play-mailer plugin inside playframework 2.5.x but I cannot seem to install it. I have read the documentation on the readMe, but can't seem to make heads or tails of it.

Here are some sample code from the documentation

To get started you add play-mailer and play-mailer-guice as a dependency in SBT:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "6.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer-guice" % "6.0.1"

play.mailer {
  host = "example.com" // (mandatory)
  port = 25 // (defaults to 25)
  ssl = no // (defaults to no)
  tls = no // (defaults to no)
  tlsRequired = no // (defaults to no)
  user = null // (optional)
  password = null // (optional)
  debug = no // (defaults to no, to take effect you also need to set the log level to "DEBUG" for the application logger)
  timeout = null // (defaults to 60s in milliseconds)
  connectiontimeout = null // (defaults to 60s in milliseconds)
  mock = no // (defaults to no, will only log all the email properties instead of sending an email)
}
```

The rest of the documentation can be found here
https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer

Can someone show me how to install and configure this plugin

When i try to install it using the sbt command I get the following errors

```
[info] Set current project to play-mailer-root (in build file:/C:/Users/Alexis/Downloads/myscript/play-mailer-root/)
```

and when I click run here is the output I get

```
[warn] Credentials file C:\Users\Alexis\.bintray\.credentials does not exist
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last play-mailer-root/compile:backgroundRun for the full output.
[error] (play-mailer-root/compile:backgroundRun) No main class detected.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your `~/.bintray/.credentials` file and run sbt again

```
realm = Bintray API Realm
host = api.bintray.com
user =
password =
```

Comment: pamu, which folder is ~/.bintray/.credentials located , because I can't find it ?

Comment: @AlexIrabor create the file in that path. if you dont find it

Comment: i am trying to do so but, the system won't allow me to name a folder .bintray, I can only name it bintray without the dot. how do I name the folder with a dot?

Comment: pamu, should the user and password be left blank ?

Comment: @AlexIrabor use mkdir command to create `mkdir ~/.bintray` and then create .credentials file using `touch ~/.bintray/.credentials` and then key values

Comment: @AlexIrabor please leave user and password blank

Answer (score 0):

add this in build.sbt :

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "6.0.0",
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer-guice" % "6.0.0",
```

after you can use :

```
play.mailer {
  host = "smtp.gmail.com" // (mandatory)
  port = 465 // (defaults to 25)
  ssl = yes // (defaults to no)
  tls = no // (defaults to no)
  tlsRequired = no // (defaults to no)
  user = "email@gmail.com"   // (optional)
  password = "password" // (optional)
  debug = no // (defaults to no, to take effect you also need to set the log level to "DEBUG" for the application logger)
  timeout = null // (defaults to 60s in milliseconds)
  connectiontimeout = 300 // (defaults to 60s in milliseconds)
  mock = no // (defaults to no, will only log all the email properties instead of sending an email)
}
```

and you can send email :

```
try {
            Email email = new Email();          
            email.setSubject(subjet);
            email.setFrom("<"+conf.getString("app.mail.from")+">");
            email.addTo("<"+to+">");
            if(fileName != null) {
                email .addAttachment(fileName, file);
            }       
            email.setBodyHtml(htmlBody);    
            mailerClient.send(email);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Logger.debug("mail() / "+e); 
            throw e;
        }
```